# Quality issue while printing with a thermal line printer from files

Tags: c#, image, printing, graphics, visual-studio-2017

I've got a thermal line printer, an Epson T88V, and I'm having problems while I try to print from files.

I'm developing a C# module that is going to form/draw image files in a cloud, then send them to a driver installed on a remote computer through net, and then this driver(also developed by me) will make my Epson print this image.

If I send my output to a printer, using *PrintDocument.print()* function and drawing my graphics with *PrintPageEventArgs* (*e.Graphics.DrawString(...)* etc...), then the print quality is high, nitid words and drawings.

Now I generate a file by this way, printing to a *Bitmap* and then saving it.
Having this saved image file, not minding the format (.tif, .jpeg, .bmp...) my printer is not performing properly when I print this file programmatically. Drawings and words get printed a little blurry, like if my Epson wasn't capable of printing the letters completely filled with color (also drawings and graphic elements).
Otherwise if I send this images to bigger printers, ink ones, my image is printed perfectly, as it should be.

I'd need some help to guess what's the difference between this two processes to learn how to fix it, or even know alternative methods for my module.
PDF files are totally discarded as alternative.

I've tried this too in very options they give:

Being "g" Bitmap's Graphics:

```
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Also, i don't reescale the Image, and I have the correct DPI.

Thanks everyone, and have a nice day.

Comment: You should [post the actual code of both of your cases](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's nothing to compare here. Also do keep in mind that when scaling gets involved, several of these "high quality" options result in _smoothing_ rather than pixel perfect reproduction.